# How to exclude lib-provided from spring boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

My spring boot war is simply too large and I want to make some optimalisation. SPring boot has the option to run war with `java -jar`, that is why `lib-provided` (with all `provided` dependecies) is still inside the war even though the dependecies are not needed there (I will never run it as standalone). Can I somehow disable this clever functionality, so that I can save some space?

UPDATE: I am using Maven and spring boot maven plugin.

Comment: Have you had a look here? http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/exclude-dependency.html

Comment: Suppose, you have to provide an info about the build tool used by you, in order to get an answer quicker.

Comment: It's in the docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Comment: What is in the docs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By Default Spring Boot Maven plugin will **repackage** your application into a executable WAR/JAR.

The **original** (i.e. non executable) artifact is renamed to **.original** by default but it is also possible to keep the original artifact using a custom classifier. refer the [Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html)

For Example:

If your app is named as MyApplication and you are trying to package it into a WAR, The following steps will happen:

1. The application will first be built as usual and you would get `MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`
2. Then spring boot maven plugin will repackage it into an executable WAR (with the same name) and it will rename the original packaged application to  `MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.original`.
3. You are now having two packaged applications:

   - `MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` (Spring boot executable)
   - `MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.original`(Non-Executable application)

You can either remove the Spring Boot Maven Plugin all together or use the Non-Executable version.

Answer (score 3):

You can update your pom file based on this doc:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/exclude-dependency.html

The only problem is that you cannot do an "exclude all"

For example:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludeGroupIds>com.packagename,com.secondpackage</excludeGroupIds>
         <excludeArtifactIds>myartifact,artifactname2</excludeArtifactIds>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Spring-Boot repackage plugin, if you are never going to it run it as standalone.
Use your normal maven war plugin (which excludes provided dependencies), which is enough for the deployed artifact.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this configuration to build.gradle to disable Repackage plugin:

```
bootRepackage.enabled = false
```

Works at least in spring boot 1.5.9